# Does the size of a database affect the operations on tables that aren't large?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For example, let's say I have a table where I'm storing "notifications" and this table really fills up over time. But then I have another table for users. If I want to perform operations on "users" will the size of the database from the notifications table affect the speed of operations on the users table?

Comment: It could, by filling up the available memory with data pages from `notifications`.  But under most circumstances, this is not going to be an issue, unless other complex queries are running concurrently.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, that's along the lines of what I was thinking could happen. No complex operations would be performed on this table, though. Most of the time the only operation will be writing to it, unless I want to add a "sent" feature so I can create notifications ahead of time...but I doubt that qualifies as a complex operation.

Comment: It's not only the size that matters, but whether the server is constantly processing notifications. If you get incessant notifications storage and querying, processes that only should hit user data and you think ought to be fast might become slow. It is a function of actual server load with regards to the server's capacity to sustain such load. However your use of the expression "over time" indicates there isn't high traffic, only accumulation.

Comment: Thanks, @jchevali Yes, notifications could be frequent, but most of the time they're going to be write-only operations. Currently we have no functionality that involves reading notifications, but we're retaining it for future records. I'm currently contemplating developing a microservice with its own database to handle out notifications, but we'll approach that if we find that it's needed...